# How can Codeblocks find my header files even without adding any search paths

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I'm learning to use OpenCV (and C++) in Codeblocks. What confuses me, however, is that when I start to include header files from OpenCV in my main.cpp file, Codeblocks automatically suggests to me the files as shown in the image below.

I have not included any search paths to project build options, so how is this possible that Codeblocks can find the files? Is there some other variable working here that I'm unaware of?

Note that I'm a beginner with both Codeblocks and OpenCV and that I only have a little experience with C++.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you installed your OpenCV headers to the standard include directory (probably /usr/include).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course when you install an IDE like `code::blocks` by default, it knows about standard path for library on your `OS`.

On my `OS` -> `Ubuntu` that is `/usr/include`

It only searches on a standard path, except you add one. If you install your library by command-line, it goes to the standard place, if you installed manually, then it depends on your option you added to installation. I can not see you screen-shot but it has access to `/usr/include` by default.

[For more detail on Linux and OpenCV](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2014/using-opencv-in-codeblocks-in-linux/)

And here is a screen-shot of codeblock on Ubuntu that I added some 3rd-party library

[image: codeblock]

---

NOTE:
if you install any libraries by command-line, just use it.
But if you have installed them manually, you need to add 2 things to codeblock.
     1. First is your path for `header` file
     2. Second is your path for `linker`

And you see it in screen-shot that say: **Search Directory**

First is for `header` and second is for `linker`