# openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory in C windows

Tags: c, openssl

**[EDIT]**

I added rsa.h file to both places still compiler can not see the rsa header.

[image: linker settings]
And here is the search directories:
[image: search directories]
I am using CodeBlocks, I already included those;

> openssl/rsa.h
>
> openssl/pem.h
>
> openssl/err.h

And by looking at from previous questions, I included openssl.lib to linker, however I still get the error I stated in title. On top of that, I downloaded the latest version of openssl. Other questions are mostly c++ but **I code in C and in windows environment**. What else can I do?

Comment: Ensure the include-search path setup for the compiler includes the folder where "openssl/rsa.h" resides

Comment: To set include directories on CodeBlocks see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802128/4658169 (the answer is for linux, but I hope the IDE has a consistent interface in the various OS)

Comment: The runtime code for openssl includes just the binaries.  The developer code adds the header files.

Answer (score 0):

CodeBlocks use minGW (.a files), I think .lib file are intended to be used with Visual studio.
check also if the it is static or dynamic linking (openssl have both)
**static** needs only .a file
**dynamic** need .a to link, and Dlls in the same directory
you need to put them in this order

**libssl.a**
**libcrypto.a**
**libgdi32.a** (used to generate random numbers from screen)